# Python tkinter: use one button to select a txt file and another to open and read contents to string

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a program that allows the user to select a file using one button:

```
    def select_file(self):
            filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=".")
            infile = open(filename, "r")
```

and another button, labeled count occurrences, should read the txt file into a string to search for what the user entered:

```
def count_occurrences(self):
    user_file = open(infile, "r")
    txt_file = user_file.read()

   # (omitted the code for counting occurrences for the sake of relevance)
```

I am unsure which function the problem lies in or if it is both.

After clicking the "select file" button, a directory name shows in the label but when I click the "count occurrences" button after entering the search text, I get the error:

"user_file = open(filename, "r") FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what is your project code, but here is the solution:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog
#import io

class ReadFileApp:
    
    def __init__(self, master):
             
        self.label = ttk.Label(master, text = "How Read a File Content!")
        self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2)
        
        ttk.Button(master, text = "Open File",
                   command = self.select_file).grid(row = 2, column = 0)

        ttk.Button(master, text = "Print the Content",
                   command = self.count_occurrences).grid(row = 2, column = 1)    

    def select_file(self):
            filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=".")
            self.infile = open(filename, "r")
            #self.infile = io.TextIOWrapper(self.infile, encoding='utf8', newline='')
            print(self.infile.name)
    
    def count_occurrences(self):
        with open(self.infile.name, 'r') as myfile:
            txt_file=myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
        print(txt_file)

def main():              
    main = Tk()
    app = ReadFileApp(main)
    main.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

this code should work perfectly fine.

your problem was:

1. The local variable infile is not visible to other functions
2. The filedialog function returns an io.TextWrapper type,  so you need to get the path as a string by calling infile.name